# How to store the value of a char*?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I found the following code for converting an int/char to binary:

```
char* int2bin(int value, char* buffer, int bufferSize) {
    char *nextChar = buffer + bufferSize-1;            // location to write the least significant bit

    *nextChar = 0;  // add the null terminator

    do {
        nextChar--;
        (value & 1) ? *nextChar  = '1' : *nextChar  = '0'; // if set set to '1' else '0'
        value = value>>1;
        if (nextChar == buffer)
          break;
    } while (value);
    return nextChar;
 }
```

I know I can do the following

```
 binString = int2bin(inputBuff[i], binaryBuffer, 17);
 fprintf (WriteTo, "%s\n", binString);
```

But I would like to now store the char I just got into the binString, one of the binary bits of the conversion, in a char array which I want to pass on elsewhere, but my lack of understanding pointers has made it difficult to know how to get it.

I tried to do this by declaring a char array and trying to store the bit:

```
char inputBuffStr[32];
```

and then...

```
binString = int2bin(inputBuff[i], binaryBuffer, 17);
inputBuffStr[i] = binString;
```

where i increases per bit as part of analysing the input, and binString is a char* type.

I get the error: A value of type "char *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "char" "inputBuffStr[i] = binString;"

If someone could maybe explain how I'd get the actual 0 or 1 that is present within binString? I don't seem to be able to understand how I can do fprintf of the value, but not output it to my char array?

Comment: This has got to be a duplicate of either pointers or C-Style strings.

Comment: It isn't quite clear what you are trying to do. Your answer is already in the `binaryBuffer` char array. `binString` *points into* `binaryBuffer`, to the first character of the answer. If you want to copy the whole answer to a different `char` array, you need to copy an array. If you only want the first character of the answer, that would be `*binString`.

Comment: At any rate, pointers and arrays and string as character arrays don't make a good topic to start learning C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use `strcpy`, which copies a `\0`-terminated C-style string:

```
char inputBuffStr[32];
strcpy(inputBuffStr,binString);
```

BTW: your question has nothing to do with C++, so I changed the tag to C.

Comment: But it is more like I wanted an array inputBuffStr to store the binString and then to store more binString which are coming in per i. So for example if binString = {'1','/0'} then inputBuffStr = {'1','/0'} but then when i increases in a loop, binString will be calculated again and so I'd like inputBuffStr to then have the value of binString added to the end of it. E.g. next binString = {'0','/0'} so now inputBuffStr = {'1','/0','0','/0'}. Eventually I need to drop the '/0' and just have one of those at the end..